# What flex-width/height does?

Tags: theme-development, logo, add-theme-support

I'm trying to understand what flex-width/flex-height parameter in custom-logo support does. Here, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-logo/ it is said that it defines *Whether to allow for a flexible height*. But what exactly it means. I also went through core and tested in my theme but can not produce what it does?

Comment: If you are using CSS and/or advanced coding to display the header image, it might not be that consequential... usually safer to set as `true`.

Comment: Related: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/flexible-custom-header-sizes/

Answer (score 1):

flex-width stands **for flexible width** and flex-height stands for **flexible height**

```
    <?php
    // Previous function code here
    $args = array(
            'default-image'      => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/default-image.jpg',
            'default-text-color' => '000',
            'width'              => 1140,
            'height'             => 250,
            'flex-width'         => false, // Now width are fixed to 1140 px
            'flex-height'        => true,  // Height is adjustable
        );
    // Later Code Here
    ?>
```